# How to upload a new Application in the play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to upload my application on playstore. I already have another application published. Is it necessary that I use the same keystore that my first application so the same package name, or can I use another keyStore? In fact I tried with a new keystore and I'm still stuck at Price and availability of the application (error)[image: error to upload in the store]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the recommended strategy for all developers is to sign all of your applications with the same certificate, throughout the expected lifespan of your applications. There are several reasons why you should do so:

**Application upgrade** – As you release ***updates to your application, you must continue to sign the updates with the same certificate or set of certificates, if you want users to be able to upgrade seamlessly to the new version***. When the system is installing an update to an application, it compares the certificate(s) in the new version with those in the existing version. If the certificates match exactly, including both the certificate data and order, then the system allows the update. If you sign the new version without using matching certificates, you must also assign a different package name to the application — in this case, the user installs the new version as a completely new application.

**Application modularity** – The Android system allows applications that are signed by the same certificate to run in the same process, if the applications so requests, so that the system treats them as a single application. In this way you can deploy your application in modules, and users can update each of the modules independently if needed.

**Code/data sharing through permissions** – The Android system provides signature-based permissions enforcement, so that an application can expose functionality to another application that is signed with a specified certificate. By signing multiple applications with the same certificate and using signature-based permissions checks, your applications can share code and data in a secure manner.

For more see [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use different keystore for different apps. But to update an existing app you must use the same keystore. For details about publishing see the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same keystore because all the information will be lost if you use another keystore like No. of Downloads etc.

Also with the existing app if you upload same app with another keystore then it will give error for having same package name.

Try to use same keystore and change the version of app. That will be beneficial for you.